# Angular 1 CSS Encapsulation

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, angular.js

I am trying to get a good clean way to do CSS Encapsulation in Angular JS.
The main goal of this is to use isolated components. This is what I have come up with so far.

The method I am using is something I have seen used with React Native.

You define a JavaScript object and place all your styling in the object and apply the styles to the template directly, in this case using `ng-style`.

JavaScript

```
styles = {
    background: 'green',
    color: 'black'
  };
```

HTML

```
<div ng-style="$ctrl.styles">
    My Component with local CSS
</div>
```

My main concern is if it will scale I believe it will as you can place the styles object into a service and inject into anywhere needed.

In theory this opens the door to mixins through lodash's `_.defaults`, theme changes through state changes and a lot of different options.

I'm just reviewing this before I consider it a viable option.

```
//Component

class myComponent {
    constructor( myCSSService ) {
        this.styles = {
            background: 'black',
            color: 'white'
        };
        this.myCSSService = myCSSService;
    }
}

myComponent.$inject = [ 'myCSSService' ];

angular.module( 'myModule', [] )
    .component( 'myComponent', {
        controller: myComponent,
        bindings: {},
        template: `
          <div ng-style="$ctrl.styles">
            My Component with local CSS
          </div>
          <div ng-style="$ctrl.myCSSService.styles">
            My Component with Injected CSS
          </div>
        `,
    } );

//Style Service

class myCSSService{
  constructor( ) {
      this.styles = {
        background: 'green',
        color: 'black'
      };
  }
}

angular.module( 'myCSSModule', [] )
    .service( 'myCSSService', myCSSService );
```